# How to get the computed mass of a Collider in Bevy / Rapier3d?

Tags: rust, bevy, rapier-3d

I have a Mesh with a ConvexDecomposition [Collider](https://docs.rs/bevy_rapier3d/latest/bevy_rapier3d/geometry/struct.Collider.html) using [`bevy_rapier3d`](https://docs.rs/bevy_rapier3d/latest/bevy_rapier3d/).

How can I figure out the mass that rapier computes for this collider?

My code looks something like this:

```rust
fn asset_loaded(
    mut commands: Commands, 
    my_object: Query<(Entity, &Handle<Mesh>), With<MyObjectMarker>>,
    meshes: Res<Assets<Mesh>>,
    asset_server: Res<AssetServer>,
    loaded: Local<bool>,
){
     if *loaded{
         return;
     }
     let (my_entity, my_mesh) = my_object.single();
     if asset_server.load_state(my_mesh) != LoadState::Loaded {
         return;
     }
     let collider = Collider::from_bevy_mesh(
         meshes.get(my_mesh).unwrap(),
         &ComputedColliderShape::ConvexDecomposition(VHACDParameters::default()),
     ).unwrap();

     // ??: how can i get the computed mass of the object here? 

     commands.get_entity(my_entity).unwrap().insert(collider);
     *loaded = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`mass_properties`](https://docs.rs/rapier3d/0.18.0/rapier3d/geometry/trait.Shape.html#tymethod.mass_properties) like so:

```rust
// ??: how can i get the computed mass of the object here?
println!("{:#?}", collider.raw.mass_properties(1.0));
```

Note that you need to specify the [`density`](https://docs.rs/rapier3d/0.18.0/rapier3d/geometry/struct.Collider.html#method.density), if not done already. In the example above it is set to `1`.

Comment: That looks really promising! Is there a way to query the density of an object dynamically? In case I want to do this in another system that's not right where the collider is created and could set it himself.

Comment: Well, that sounds `bevy` specific, but I am pretty sure it should be possible to do that. However, be aware that the _mass properties_ of a `Collider` may [only be set at creation](https://www.rapier.rs/docs/user_guides/bevy_plugin/colliders#mass-properties).

Comment: I figured it out, and added a second answer for people that might need it. Thanks so much, the `.raw` part was what I couldn't figure out for some reason :).

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to handle the general case where you might have specified `ColliderMassProperties`, you could use the following:

```rust
fn query_object_mass(object: Query<&Collider, Option<&ColliderMassProperties>>) {
    let (collider, mass_properties) = object.single();
    let mass = match mass_properties {
        None => collider.raw.mass_properties(1.0).mass(),
        Some(ColliderMassProperties::Density(d)) => collider.raw.mass_properties(*d).mass(),
        Some(ColliderMassProperties::Mass(m)) => *m,
        Some(ColliderMassProperties::MassProperties(mp)) => mp.mass,
    }; 
}
```